# How to grant access only to the Root Account User for an S3 bucket with IAM Policy AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to create an s3 bucket policy that only the Root Account can have full access, how can I do that?

Example:

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [            
        {
            "Sid": "Allow full access for root account user",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ih-deploy-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ih-deploy-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Or adding a Condition Like

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals" : {"aws:username" : "rootUser"} 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of the very few (if not the only) usecase for an explicit `Deny` with a `NotPrincipal`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<your-account-number>:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::ih-deploy-bucket/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::ih-deploy-bucket"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This will explicitly deny all principals that are not (and not *only*) the root account user, including IAM users, assumed role sessions and federated users in that account.
And since the root user always has explicit Allows for all actions on all resources, an actual Allow is given by the root user's identity-based permissions, so the root user will have access to that bucket.

The reason why this works is that a caller identity working in your account has always multiple principals simultaneously, which are being evaluated by IAM for a policy statement:

1. the account principal `arn:aws:iam::<your-account-number>:root`
2. the user, assumed role or federated user principal

In the case of an explicit `Allow` if you only used the root account principal in a `Principal` rule in a policy statement, then *any* user in that account will match the allow and will be given access, since the account principal is always part of a user's principal list in that account.

However, in the case of a `Deny` with a `NotPrincipal`, things are a bit different. Here, the list of `NotPrincipal`s must whitelist *all* principals of the caller's identity to be not denied.

This fact somewhat shines through in the AWS documentation about `NotPrincipal`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html

> When you use NotPrincipal with Deny, you must also specify the account
> ARN of the not-denied principal. Otherwise, the policy might deny
> access to the entire account containing the principal. Depending on
> the service that you include in your policy, AWS might validate the
> account first and then the user. If an assumed-role user (someone who
> is using a role) is being evaluated, AWS might validate the account
> first, then the role, and then the assumed-role user.

Comment: "make sure to get the account id in that statement correct, as otherwise you will lose complete access to this bucket, including with your root account user!" this is not correct since root always has permission to put bucket policy

Answer (score 0):

```
"AWS": "root"
```

should be changed to

```
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<your-account-number>:root"
```

Comment: I tried that, this is not the root Account according to this AWS page ->

When you specify an AWS account, you can use the account ARN (arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:root), or a shortened form that consists of the AWS: prefix followed by the account ID.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#Principal_specifying

Comment: This grants to all users in the Account.

Comment: @LeonardoCampanha No, this is not true. It will NOT grant access to all IAM users.

Answer (score -1):

Like httpdigest said in this answer, the root user always has explicit Allows for all actions on all resources.

So what I blocked all permissions to all others users that are not in condition. And the root user has always access.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [            
        {
            "Sid": "Block all user not in condition, but the root has permission",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ],
              "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "175.222.100.192"
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:username": "user1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The question was how to grant to the root, but the root always has the permission, I didn't know that. 

I used another approach, instead to grant permission specific to the root, because the root has always the permission I denied everyone else..
The condition is only an example that I used to specify who can also access instead of the root user.